# Custom Object Detection on Azure Machine Learning or Databricks

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, gpu, azure-ml

I'm looking to train a custom object detection model using Tensorflow's API. Is it possible to do it in Azure ML Studio or in Databricks?

Object Detection link - https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

Can this be setup without using COCO?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this question? I have the same question and was wondering if you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to do it in Azure ML Studio. Sorry for the delayed response. @Amaan